# Magento not showing images even if they are in the server

Tags: image, magento

I've installed a Magento theme I bought and since the very first moment it doesn't load images. The weird thing is this:

The site show this:

[image]

If I get the url of the first image (Right Click: "Get image url") shows this:

`http://ecobiobella.com/media/resized/s/blog/5.jpg`

I navigate to this url the images don't exist and I get a 404 error.

The weird thing is that that image is IN MY server and accessible from the server, like this:

[image]

As last thing in the root folder `public_html` I loaded the same image and that gets showed up:

http://ecobiobella.com/5.jpg

I'm not understanding what I'm doing wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the media folder for a .htaccess file and remove it.